# Java/Scala Extract email and a string with format email[delimiter]string

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have a bunch of strings that I'm looking to parse in the following format and extract just the email and string which is followed by a delimiter

```
email[delimiter]string
```

In other words 
[email with any ascii characters][delimiter][string with any ascii characters]

The delimiters can be ,;:| or ||
e.g.

```
abc@xyz.com,blah
abc@xyz.au;blah1
abc@xyz.ru:blah2
abc@xyz.ru|blah,2
abc@xyz.ru||blah2
```

My progress so far is following regex to match the above strings, however how can I modify this regex so that I can form appropriate groups to extract only the email and the string which is followed by the delimiter in Java/Scala

```
.+@.+([:;,|])+.+$
```

The java code would look something like this:

```
// Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Email: " + m.group(0));
            System.out.println("Value: " + m.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
```

Comment: Think your string like ((email)(anything)) then you only need to get he 1st group

Comment: Just a note - `group(0)` is the entire match. I think you want `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm doing in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, answering my own question with what I got working. Regex experts - any holes you can find here, please?

```
Pattern COMPILE = Pattern.compile("(.+@[A-Za-z0-9.\"]+)(?:[:;,|]+)(.*)");
Matcher m = COMPILE.matcher(next);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
} else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

EDIT : Edited to use non capturing group as per MYGz's answer

Comment: You can also use non capturing group. `"(.+@.+)(?:[:;,|]+)(.*)"`, then `m.group(1)`, `m.group(2)`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have worked out the regex part for yourself. I have a suggestion for result extraction: use [kantan.regex](https://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.regex/).

This allows you to write:

```
import kantan.regex.implicits._

// Declare your regular expression, validated at compile time.
val regex = rx"(.+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+)(?:[:;,|]+)(.*)"

// Sample input
val input = "abc@xyz.com,blah"

// Returns an Iterator[(String, String)] on all matches, where
// ._1 is the email and ._2 the string
input.evalRegex[(String, String)](regex)
```

Note that you might want to use better typed values for this - a case class rather than a `(String, String)`, say. This is also possible - you can either provide decoders yourself, or let shapeless derive them:

```
import kantan.regex.generic._

// Case class in which to store results.
case class MailMatch(mail: String, value: String)

// Returns an Iterator[MailMatch]
input.evalRegex[MailMatch](regex)
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\\w+@\\w+)[:;,\\|](.+)$
```

Then use Java to extract the groups from the Match.  Group 1 is the email and group 2 is the string after the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something ?